# Passing checkbox items to ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list of items I want to send to an ASP.NET Core MVC controller. I want to send the name of all checked items but instead of passing it to the method, the items get posted on the URL.

In this example I'd like to pass the `FullFilePath` and `FullFolderPath` parameters.

The view

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="FullFilePath" value="@Model[0].FullFilePath">
    <input type="hidden" name="FullFolderPath" value="@Model[0].FullFolderPath">
<table id="myTable" class="table CustomColorTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                    <i class="bi bi-folder2"></i>
                </div>
                <div>Select All</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                    <i class="bi bi-folder2"></i>
                </div>
                <div>Folder Name</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                    <i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text"></i>
                </div>
                <div>File Name</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                    <i class="bi bi-calendar2-check"></i>
                </div>
                <div>Date Modified</div>
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="header">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="@item.FullFilePath" id="@item.FullFilePath">
                        </div>
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FolderName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateModified)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="btnSubmit" class="btnClick" asp-controller="Directory" asp-action="DownloadAll">Download Selected Items</button>
</form>
```

The controller methods - this one populates the view:

```
public IActionResult GetFiles(string fullfolderPath)
{
    // Fetch all files in the Folder (Directory).
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(fullfolderPath);

    // Copy File names to Model collection.
    List<FileViewModel> files = new List<FileViewModel>();

    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        files.Add(new FileViewModel 
                { 
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath), 
                    FolderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)),
                    FullFilePath = filePath,
                    DateModified = new FileInfo(filePath).LastWriteTime,
                    FileCount = Directory.GetFiles(fullfolderPath).Length,
                    FullFolderPath = fullfolderPath,
                });
    }

    return View(files);
}
```

This is where I wish to send the array of checked items and it's folder name.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DownLoadAll(string FullFolderPath, string[] FullfilePath)
{
    if (FullFolderPath == null)
    {
        return View();
    }     

    // Build the File Path.
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(FullFolderPath);
    var zipName = $"TestFiles-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss")}.zip";

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       // required: using System.IO.Compression;
       using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
       {
           // Query the Products table and get all image content
           foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
           {
               var entry = zip.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(filePath));

               using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(filePath.Length))
               using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
               {
                   fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
               }
           };
       }

       return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Model Binding binds the property by matching the `name` of the inputs.

2.If you do not specify the form method, it will send the data by url to corresponding get method.

Change your code like below:

```
@model List<FileViewModel>
<form method="post">        //add method="post"
         @*if you do not want to pass it to `string[] FullfilePath`, pls change the name*@
    <input type="hidden" name="OtherFullFilePath" value="@Model[0].FullFilePath">
    <input type="hidden" name="FullFolderPath" value="@Model[0].FullFolderPath">
    <table id="myTable" class="table CustomColorTable" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow"><i class="bi bi-folder2"></i></div><div>Select All</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow"><i class="bi bi-folder2"></i></div>
                    <div>Folder Name</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow"><i class="bi bi-file-earmark-text"></i></div>
                    <div>File Name</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="icon icon-shape bg-indigo text-white rounded-circle shadow"><i class="bi bi-calendar2-check"></i></div>
                    <div>Date Modified</div>
                </th>    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="header">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                                            @*set the name FullFilePath and value*@
                            <input type="checkbox" name="FullFilePath" value="@item.FullFilePath" id="@item.FullFilePath">
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FolderName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateModified)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btnClick" asp-controller="Directory" asp-action="DownloadAll">Download Selected Items</button>
</form>
```